# Google play Games ,automatch

Tags: google-play-games

How can I disable **random auto match** from the **player-picker UI**
In my case I really don't want this feature,so please tell me how to disable it.
Is there any way???
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMultiplayer#createMatch(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.turnbased.TurnBasedMatchConfig)), if the `allowAutomatch` parameter is set to `false`, the UI will not display an option for selecting automatch players. Set this to false if your game does not want to support automatching.